# EC2 micro instance memory issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins

I am running a micro instace in EC2 with 592 MB available RAM

Jenkins was crashing due to Out Of Memory build errors while running UPDATE on big SQL Table in backend.

Disk utilisation is 83% with 6 GB out of 8GB EBS volume used ..

```
sudo du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
/
2.7G    opt
1.5G    var
1.2G    usr
```

I found only 6 MB was free with command - "free -m " with these services running -

```
(i) LAMPP
(ii) Jenkins
(iii) Mysql 5.6
```

I stopped LAMPP and that created 70 MB free space

Then , I closed Jenkins, it created 320 MB free space
Closing MySQL 5.6 brings it up to 390 MB free space ..

So, 200MB RAM is still getting used with none of my services running.

```
Is 200MB RAM minimum required for an Ubuntu micro Instance running on Amazon EC2 ?
```

Comment: is that MySQL 5.6 running on the same Micro Instance? And is whole Jenkins running or just the agent part? I suggest a Master-slave architecture with at least a Mini style Master and (as many as you like) slaves. Master has the MySQL + Jenkins, slaves have the builder agents.

Comment: yeah i have whole jenkins running on same server with everything else.   So master SQL and jenkins run on 1 instance  and lampp + slave runs on other instances. I have also redis + node ( as reverse proxy from apache ) BTW .. - any place to fit in caching from redis - should that be another instance too ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, i believe it can run till its 100% used.

If a task that requires a large memory than what is available, the task is killed.

To free up more memory space, you can run this from your terminal

`sudo apt-get autoremove`